# TextView text assignment with call to string.xml file not working

Tags: android, xml, string, textview, android-studio

I am trying to concatenate a saved string value to a counter label within afterTextChanged() method, but the setText() method is breaking and throwing an exception. Not sure what I'm missing here.

```
@Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            counterLabel.setText(characterMax - editable.toString().length() + (R.string.charactersRemaining));
```

Comment: can you please share the exception ?

Comment: [It wasn't hard to find](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)... Next time please spend some time on google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R.string.charactersRemaining` Is actually a unique id (int) that represents your String.

To get that string use `getString(R.string.charactersRemaining)`.